# How can I combine two arrays of SimpleXML elements?

Tags: php, xml, soap

The first array is the location and the second is the cars with their associated prices. How can I combine them like the sample below?

```
Array
(
    [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [companyLocationInfo] => Array
                (
                    [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                        (
                            [companyName] => AVIS
                            [name] => NYCC07
                            [line1] => 420 EAST 90TH STREET
                        )
                    [2] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                        (
                            [companyName] => AVIS
                            [name] => NYCC06
                            [line1] => 310 EAST 64TH STREET
                        )
                    [3] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                        (
                            [companyName] => AVIS
                            [name] => NYCC01
                            [line1] => 68 EAST 11TH STREET
                        )

                )

            [rates] => Array
                (
                    [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                        (
                            [companyName] => AVIS
                            [name] => NYCC07
                            [vehicleRentalPrefType] => CCAR
                            [rateAmount] => 83.99
                            [rateCurrency] => USD
                        )
                    [2] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                        (
                            [companyName] => AVIS
                            [name] => NYCC06
                            [vehicleRentalPrefType] => CCAR
                            [rateAmount] => 110.54
                            [rateCurrency] => USD
                        )
                    [3] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                        (
                            [companyName] => AVIS
                            [name] => NYCC01
                            [vehicleRentalPrefType] => CCAR
                            [rateAmount] => 210.65
                            [rateCurrency] => USD
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

I would like to combine them like this:

```
AVIS 420 EAST 90TH STREET
CCAR 83.99 USD

AVIS 310 EAST 64TH STREET
CCAR 110.54 USD

AVIS 68 EAST 11TH STREET
CCAR 210.65 USD
```

With PHP how can I combine it like this?

---

I just got an answer on my question but I can't get it work correctly, I want to combine to arrays, the first is the locations and the second is the cars, but in the second one is there another array which I have to match the values to the first array,

Here is an example below,

```
Array
(
    [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [companyLocationInfo] => Array
                (
                    [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                        (
                            [companyName] => AVIS
                            [name] => NYCC07
                            [line1] => 420 EAST 90TH STREET
                        )
                    [2] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                        (
                            [companyName] => AVIS
                            [name] => NYCC06
                            [line1] => 310 EAST 64TH STREET
                        )
                    [3] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                        (
                            [companyName] => AVIS
                            [name] => NYCC01
                            [line1] => 68 EAST 11TH STREET
                        )

                )

            [rates] => Array
                (
                    [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                        (
                            [pickupDropoffLocations] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                        (
                                            [companyName] => AVIS
                                            [name] => NYCC07
                                        )
                                )
                            [vehicleRentalPrefType] => CCAR
                            [rateAmount] => 83.99
                            [rateCurrency] => USD
                        )
                    [2] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                        (
                            [pickupDropoffLocations] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                        (
                                            [companyName] => AVIS
                                            [name] => NYCC06
                                        )
                                )
                            [vehicleRentalPrefType] => CCAR
                            [rateAmount] => 110.54
                            [rateCurrency] => USD
                        )
                    [3] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                        (
                            [pickupDropoffLocations] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                        (
                                            [companyName] => AVIS
                                            [name] => NYCC01
                                        )
                                )
                            [vehicleRentalPrefType] => CCAR
                            [rateAmount] => 210.65
                            [rateCurrency] => USD
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

And this is the code what I'm using, but not working,

```
$results_array = array();

foreach($result[0]->rates as $rate) {
    foreach($result[0]->companyLocationInfo as $info) {
        if($info->name == $rate->pickupDropoffLocations[0]->name) {
            $results_array[] = array(
                'line1' => $info->line1,
                'name' => $info->locationDetails->name,
                'companyName' => $info->companyName,
                'vehicleRentalPrefType' => $rate->vehicleRentalPrefType
            );
        }
    }
}
print_r($results_array);
```

And I want it should looks like:

```
AVIS 420 EAST 90TH STREET
CCAR 83.99 USD

AVIS 310 EAST 64TH STREET
CCAR 110.54 USD

AVIS 68 EAST 11TH STREET
CCAR 210.65 USD
```

Can someone tell the problem of that code?

Comment: By order and sort do you mean combine? If you truly mean order or sort then please define the parameters that should be used to order it.

Comment: In that case I suggest you edit your question accordingly so that some may answer it more easily.

Answer (score 0):

To combine .. something like this, perhaps ?

```
$results = array();

foreach($array[0]->companyLocationInfo as $info) {
    foreach($array[0]->rates as $rate) {
        if($info->name == $rate->name) {
            $results[] = array(
                'line1' => $info->line1,
                'name' => $info->name,
                'companyName' => $info->companyName,
                'vehicleRentalPrefType' => $rate->vehicleRentalPrefType
            );
        }
    }
}
```

and then do loop for you `$results`

Comment: Thank you, but I have a problem with the if function `if($info->rentalLocation->address->locationDetails->name == $rate->pickupDropoffLocations[0]->locationDescription->name)` it returns empty, why?

Comment: Hard to say, coz i don't know your data for example i cant see any locationDescription data or pickupDropoffLocations or so.. could you print part of real data here?

Comment: Please look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10741293/combining-two-arrays-not-working-php)

Comment: Still cant see where is rentalLocation, or address or locationdetails elements .

Please improve your question here. You don't need separate question.

Comment: I dont want to delete the previous question, should I hit `Answer Your Question`?

Comment: I'm quite new here too, you can edit your post and update the SimpleXMLElement output there.

Comment: Please look at my question again, tnx

Comment: You didnt answered my question,

Comment: Yes, and that indicates that _i dont know_ answer. What does var_dump($result); output?

Comment: var_dump($result) returns an empty array.

Comment: So, if it is empty, foreach($result[0]->rates as $rate) is also empty.

Comment: When I make var_dump($results_array) then returns empty but var_dump($results) it returns the whole array

Comment: but why you first said it returns empty? i cannot help you if you dont help me by giving correct output etc. im out.

Answer (score 0):

Try array object (http://php.net/arrayobject) insert it :)